# Fixing AutoHotkey function for adding a fixed charge

Tags: performance, function, autohotkey

Full disclosure:  I didn't write this script.  I am improving this after the person who wrote it left the company.

This script is very simple, it adds what we call a "fixed charge" to an account once a ticket number has been entered and then the key combo of "ctrl + alt + insert" is used.

Script works perfectly except when the account already has a "fixed charge".  In that case, the autohotkey won't work.  The solution of the person who wrote this script was to just assign another key combo to add the fixed charge.

I think that there has to be an easier way to do this i.e. force the key combo thru or use an if statement.  I have never written an autohotkeys function before and my understanding of autohotkeys is very limited.

I would like to adapt the script below to work on every account regardless whether another fixed charge is already on the account.

```
  ^!Insert::
      Send, !t
      Send, !x
      Send {Tab 3}
      Send, 41025
      Send, {Enter}
      Send, !o
      Sleep, 3000
      Send !{c 3}
  Return
```

Comment: Sure you can use an if statement, but first you have to find a way of determining if you need to do thing A or thing B. There are many different ways to do this in AutoHotkey. A simple solution could be to navigate into a text filed and copy its contents to the clipboard, then do something like `If Clipboard = "fixed charge"` ... A more sophisticated way could be to use [ControlGet](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGet.htm). This is not always possible though. You have to check using the AHK window spy utility. And a really hacky way could be using PixelGetColor...

Answer (score 0):

One option if you can *highlight* the text that says 'fixed charge' is to preface your hotkey like so:

```
^!Insert::
  click, 711, 431
  clipboard = ; empty your clipboard
  send ^a^c ; select all and copy
  ClipWait, 0.25 ; wait for something to enter your clipboard
  text := clipboard
  If(InStr(text, "fixed charge"))
  {
      Send, !t
      Send, !x
      Send {Tab 3}
      Send, 41025
      Send, {Enter}
      Send, !o
      Sleep, 3000
      Send !{c 3}
  }
Return
```

You can get the X, Y coordinates by using windows spy, which you can run by right-clicking the AutoHotkey icon.

If you *cannot* highlight text in your system you will have to find something that autohotkey can pickup that has changed. There are many possible ways, like [ControlGet](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGet.htm), detecting a file change, or even doing the script in another way to modify the output of your in-house software. AutoHotkey is as much art as it is science. The easiest way to figure it out is to throw stuff at the wall and hope it sticks.